# Как выполнить код из пустого сектора MBR?

Tags: python, windows, mbr

Насколько я знаю, в MBR есть неиспользуемый пустой сектор. Можно ли записать в этот пустой сектор определённую команду, которая бы выполнялась каждый раз при включении системы? Если можно, то с помощью какого скрипта это можно сделать? Важное примечание— запись должна происходить без использования GUI, через командную строку или с использованием языка ассемблера. Также, если это возможно, осуществить это нужно без прав администратора. ОС— Windows 7/10/11.

Comment: И какое вредоносное ПО вы пытаетесь изобразить? 

Comment: Подозреваю, что написать что-то в MBR без прав администратора не получится. И запустить, не трогая при этом основной загрузочный сектор MBR, полагаю, тоже. И согласен с @Amgarak, что-то вы не доброе замышляете.

Comment: Никакое, я вообще таким не занимаюсь, мне это нужно для автоматизации операционки.

Comment: @aa_talanin, ну я хотя бы попытаюсь.

Comment: @aa_talanin, в целом, мне главное чтобы команда в MBR запустилась любой ценой, главное поместить её именно в нужный пустой сектор, чтобы не перезаписать весь MBR и желательно ничего не сломать.

Comment: Если вам нужно что-то низкоуровневое написать, что выполнялось бы до старта ОС, то вам придется костылить процесс загрузки и переписывать основной загрузочный сектор, чтобы сначала загружалась ваша программа, а уже потом по необходимости основная ОС. Но в таком случае полезность вашей программы будет весьма ограничена, потому что она будет иметь только низкоуровневый доступ к тому, что ей биос дал, без любых плюшек от ОС. Если вам нужно как-то с основной системой взаимодействовать, то я бы не лез в MBR и просто в юзер спейсе ОС засунулся бы в автозагрузку. А вообще я не спец по правкам MBR.

Comment: @aa_talanin, там задача в том, чтобы разместить на диске C определённый файл, а в MBR пописать «автозагрузку» этого файла, чтобы он запускался каждый раз, при запуске самой ОС. И нет, autorun.inf или что-то подобное мне не подойдёт.

Comment: @aa_talanin, но всё равно большое спасибо, буду пробовать что-то сделать.